# How to change layout to only one method in spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I am new to the spree world ( using 3.0.0 ), and i want to override the layout used for a custom product method that i added as following:

in "app/controllers/spree/api/products_controller.rb" i did:

```
Spree::API::ProductsController.class_eval do

  def custom_view 

  end

end
```

And after modifiying the routes accordingly i was able to display to view as wished...

Then i added the layout before filter to remove the default spree layout

```
Spree::API::ProductsController.class_eval do

  layout nil
  layout spree_application, :except => :custom_view

  def custom_view 

  end

end
```

But it didn't work, and the spree layout kept displaying.

How to remove the spree layout only for this custom method ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use Deface Overrides with a :remove tag for the specific targeted element.
Hope your problem gets solved by doing this Way